# How to avoid SSL Error on browser while accessing SSL enabled service on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have deployed a WCF service on IIS and enabled SSL for it. I created a self signed certificate on the server and exported into a pfx file. I also brought the pfx to my machine and installed it under `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.

When I hit the service URL, I get following warning which I need to avoid:

> You attempted to reach 172.150.170.226, but instead you actually
>   reached a server identifying itself as something.something.local.

Please suggest. Thank You.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. Did you get the error on your local machine only or does this happen on the server as well?

Comment: I am getting this warning on my local machine when I call this service using external ip of the server.I get similar warning on the server when i use localhost.

Comment: try using the machine name instead of ip or localhost.

Comment: web page i not available error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was unable to name the self signed certificate according to my preference.I was accessing the service through the ip address of the server , so i needed to set the common name of the certificate as that ip.

I was able to do this using SelfSSL.exe which comes with IIS 6.0 Resource kit.Using this tool from command line I was able to name the certificate as i like.

Answer (score 1):

The host name on the certificate has to match the host name in the URL you are using. So you need to be hitting something.something.local. If that doesn't work, then maybe it needs to be set up in your hosts file so that the IP resolution works.